# How to register ActSkin4.ocx for Windows 8 64 bits on Visual Basic 98?

Tags: windows-8, registry, ocx, visual-studio-6

I have a old project in visual basic 98 And this project use this OCX

ActSkin4.ocx

But when I tried to execute in windows 8 64 bits Visual can't execute that

I tried to register that using command line but no luck I have this error:

[image: this is the error]

What can I do?

Comment: This is an ancient 32-bit control.  You have to use c:\windows\syswow64\regsvr32.exe, the 32-bit version, and run it from an elevated command prompt.  Maybe that works, not using the vendor's  installer is in general a fail-whale due to missing dependent DLLs and a missing license key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an ancient 32-bit control. You have to use c:\windows\syswow64\regsvr32.exe, the 32-bit version, and run it from an elevated command prompt. Maybe that works, not using the vendor's installer is in general a fail-whale due to missing dependent DLLs and a missing license key by @hans-passant